# Open up another asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net page and in my TextBox1_Click I would like to open up another asp.net page from my package.

The page is called `Submitted.aspx`.  How do I open that up using c# from `Index.aspx` in the TextBox1_Click method?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried?

Comment: Does any server-side processing need to happen during this click event?  If not, you should really consider just using javascript, to avoid the unnecessary server round-trip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
Server.Transfer("Submitted.aspx");
```

From inside of your event.  Depending on what you're trying to do you may want to add a button and fire that click event instead.

Comment: Thank you sir, you are a star!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
Response.Redirect("Submitted.aspx");
```